# Jni - Call c++ method from java using void pointers

Tags: java, c++, callback, java-native-interface, void-pointers

Is there any way to call a native (c++) method from java using the method's function pointer?

Basically i want to use this for callbacks. Once a certain event in java get's fired, i want java to call a c++ method. Java will not know about that method at compile time - it's created later in a seperate c++ library - so i need to somehow pass the method from c++ to java at runtime.

My idea was to pass a function pointer as int (`void(*)(args)` for example) and make java resolve the c++ method.

For clarification - In c++ i have something like this:

```
void callback(args)
{
    ...
}

...

// Use jni to call java method "registerSomeJavaCallback()"
//
registerSomeJavaCallback((int)&callback)
```

Now in java i need something like this:

```
void registerSomeJavaCallback(int fpointer) {
    native void m = getNativeMethodFromPointer(fpointer) // <- This
    //
    // ... Register event that fires m as callback
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the JNI function `RegisterNatives`  I think it might let you dynamically register native methods for Java to call see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17734

Comment: I had a look at that method and it seems to be what i'm looking for, i think i can register my voids as natives and do the java part with reflection. Thank you! Can you post this as an answer so i can tag it as the correct one?

Comment: else nvm, i'll post a clean answer tomorrow once i've merged everything into a working example using your information. Thanks anyways!

Comment: If you get it working please post your answer.  It was only a guess and I don't have the project setup to create a test-bed at the moment.

Comment: Please remember that `RegisterNatives` must work from `JniOnLoad`, and this may not answer your expectations of *dynamic*. For fully dynamic solution of void callbacks with predefined set of args, you should create your custom JNI thunk (a native method that accepts a callback pointer as **jlong** and all the necessary arguments, and passes control to that callback pointer).

Comment: @AlexCohn Could you provide an example? I think this could be a good approach but i rarely find anything about thunks with jni. Could this be used to rellocate my example with function pointers?

Comment: I am not speaking about some true 'thunks'. Here is a simplified example: [C side](https://gist.github.com/alexcohn/c41d53683efec541e679f847f068fe33) and [Java side](https://gist.github.com/alexcohn/dab19f6f836483545fcb47918a2af4c8).

Comment: Ah, i see! Well, by now i'm working on a solution that is very similar to yours. At the moment i'm busy with other stuff but when it's done i will post my solution as an answer. Thanks for your contribution!